# how can I transfer entries between MSM sites if the site's already been created?

Tags: multi-site-manager

We created a separate site in MSM a while back and never copied over channels, fields or categories. But now we want to do this without deleting and recreating the site. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there's not really an easy way. What I did was in the second MSM site:

1. Duplicate channels
2. Duplicate field groups, fields etc.
3. Duplicate categories
4. Duplicate file upload prefs.

With 1-3 above we used the EXACT same url title. Then we wrote this script to copy all the entries over, retaining their category assignments.

I hope this helps someone.

https://gist.github.com/jaseclamp/2dcda64e8912f7361d94